# Window Task Scheduler problem with python when running on internal network

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, windows-task-scheduler

I have a question.

I am currently using the company's internal network.

And I made the company's work automately using python.

And I created python script as an executable file using the pyinstaller library.

It works normally on the external network.

however,

When running on an internal network,

One task runs and does not move on to the next task.

For example,

```
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
pg.sleep(5)


url = 'https://etk.srail.kr/'
driver.get(url)
pg.sleep(5)
```

If I write the code like this, Chrome Driver will run,

and It stops at the part where you access the URL.

May I know why this is happening??

I already ask to ChatGPT. but it can't solve the problem...

Comment: `I already ask to ChatGPT` if you ask a vague question you'll get a vague answer *especially* from statistical text generators like ChatGPT that don't really understand what you say or their own answer. You didn't mention any error messages so what does `it stops` even mean? Perhaps your script crashed? Perhaps the account has no permission to install or use ChromeDriver? Perhaps you can't download ChromeDriver like this? Or the URL is wrong? Did you check the script's logs? If the script has no logs, add them and log any exceptions

Comment: `External` and `internal` network don't mean much either. Do you mean when you try to connect to URLs in the internal or external network? Or when you try to run the program inside or outside the company network? Perhaps the URL is wrong? Have you tried running the script directly?